# Accessibility Larger Text affecting UITableViewCell padding when using Custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am using a Custom `UITableViewCell` that I have laid out in my Storyboard. I am using a custom iOS font and am not using dynamic text for this `UITableView`.

However, when I make the text larger using iOS accessibility it does affect my `UITableViewCell`, likely the padding from the bottom of the `contentView` as it seems to push all of the labels and views up.

[image]

**Is there a way to prevent dynamic text from affecting my `UITableViewCell` layout?**

Comment: Is it a layout from top to bottom? `label`Set `top space`? Font changes will definitely affect the layout. Check if your layout is reasonable.

Comment: Labels were anchored to the bottom. I found the fix, I just need to case everything off of the horizontal center.

Comment: @NicHubbard could you please share your solution ?

Comment: @dip Make sure your views have constrains to the x axis of the cell instead of the top or bottom.

Comment: Would you mind providing an answer marked as accepted in order to inform interested people that a solution has been found out for this problem, please? 